# Trigger method from another class

Tags: java, swing, class

So,i have 2 classes with one jframe each.

In the main one,the user puts data inside some textfields and then saves the data in a file.
In the second one he will be able to read the saved files and preview the data that is inside of them.I this second jframe i want a button that can send the file name to the main class and start a method that will read the data from the file and put it back into the textfields so it can be editted.

So,i need to send some data(a string,filename) to another class and trigger a method inside that class/jframe based on that data.How can i do that ?

Thanks and have a good day !

EDIT :

Doing this :

Second class :

```
 Test2 test2 = new Test2();
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"-"+ serializedPath+"-");//to see if the path is right
 test2.editare(serializedPath);
```

It is not triggering the method in my first jframe.
I tried triggering the method from the same class with the same path,it works just fine.
What am i doing wrong ?
Isn't it trying to trigger it inside the second class ?
It gives no errors though...

Answer (score 1):

JFrame is a regular Java object. When you create frames, you can pass it to be called later:

```
JMainFrame jMainFrame = new JMainFrame(...);
JSecondaryFrame jSecondaryFrame = new JSecondaryFrame(...);
jSecondaryFrame.setMainFrame(jMainFrame);    // sets the object field value
```

Then in an `ActionListener` you could access this `jSecondaryFrame.jMainFrame.readData()`.

Comment: Could you please take a look at my edit and tell me if i'm doing anything wrong ?

Comment: It's almost impossible to say what is wrong from this code excerpt. If you require further assistance, try minimizing your code and create an [SSSCE](http://sscce.org/). I have too many guesses for what could be wrong there - an ignored exception, overridden method, typo, anything...

Comment: I understand.So if i call test2.editare it will trigger that method inside which class? I tried triggering other methods from the second class to execute inside the first class and they aren't getting executed

Comment: This makes no sense, methods are always executed. Try googling for debugging with java in Eclipse or Idea and use `System.out.println` to print debug messages.

Comment: I've added `test2.setVisible(true);` before `test2.editare(serializedPath);` It opens another main frame but inside that new main frame it does what i want..i can't understand anything,lol